# Convert long single line command to a bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

Im working on the following command in crontab:

```
nice --20 iperf3 -c somelocation.com -f k | while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$(date) $line"; done | tee onespeed.txt | tee -a speeds.txt; sleep 30 ;cat onespeed.txt | grep sender >> concentrated.txt; sleep 2 ;cat onespeed.txt | grep sender | awk -F' ' '{print $13}' | while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$(date) $line"; done | tee onerawspeed.txt | tee -a rawspeeds.txt
```

I understand that the job could be done in a far more elegant way but Im looking to find out how I go about breaking this down so that its structured properly to act as a bash shell script.

Specifically Im focused on structuring it over multiple lines so that it is more readable.

Comment: Just replace the `;` with newlines.

Comment: Also, if you have set EDITOR to something you can use, C-x C-e will open the current command line in that editor, so you do not have to copy-paste-and-mistake your carefully crafted command line.

Comment: I suggest to replace `cat file | grep something` by `grep something file` and `cat file | grep something | awk -F' ' '{print $13}'` by `awk -F' ' '/something/ {print $13}' file`.

Comment: what's the expected output? I think you're making this far too complicated. You want 4 output files: onerawspeed.txt, rawspeeds.txt, onespeed.txt, and concentrated.txt. What do you want to put in each one of them?

Comment: @Cyrus Good advice thanks. Ill be condensing the whole thing down but it was more the concept of breaking down long commands like this into more readable scripts :)

Comment: @MarcLambrichs Yes its defitiely overcomplicated at the moment but each file was output just to show me what I was achieving as each part of the process does its job. Ultimately I want to have a file that has two columns, one for unix time and one for the speed achieved by the test in k. This will be fed into an RRD.

Comment: You don't put anything this complicated in a crontab. You save your script to a file, and call that script from the crontab.

Comment: To get started: 1) Replace every `;` with a newline. 2) Add a newline after every `|`. 3) Indent code within conditionals and loops. See [@agc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46341516/1745001).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nice --20 iperf3 -c somelocation.com -f k | while IFS= read -r line; do 
echo "$(date) $line" 
done | tee onespeed.txt | tee -a speeds.txt
sleep 30 
grep "sender" onespeed.txt >> concentrated.txt
sleep 2 
awk -F' ' '/sender/ {print $13}' onespeed.txt | while IFS= read -r line; do
echo "$(date) $line"
done | tee onerawspeed.txt | tee -a rawspeeds.txt
```

**EDIT :** 
I have updated the script, following the comments advices

Comment: None of the `cat` program calls are necessary, `grep` takes filenames as its rightmost arguments.  Why not take `concentrated.txt` as input to the `awk` rather than doing the same `grep` again?

Comment: @Will thanks for this. It answers my question perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's not clear what you really want to put in all those output files, I'll give an example of how to write separate values to different files.

The bitrate p/sec per interval and the average Bitrate that iperf3 produces can be put -separely- into a file like this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {OFS="\t";f1="speed.txt";f2="sender.txt"}
$6~/MBytes/{print strftime(), $7 >> f1; close(f1)}
/sender/{print strftime(), $7 >> f2; close(f2)}
```

which can be called like this:

```
$ iperf3 -c server -f k --forceflush | awk -f tst.awk
```

or, in one line:

```
 iperf3 -c server -f k --forceflush | awk -v f1=speed.txt -v f2=sender.txt \
    'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}                                          \
     $6~/MBytes/{print strftime(), $7 >> f1; close(f1)}       \
     /sender/{print strftime(), $7 >> f2; close(f2)}'
```

which print sysdate and Bitrate to each file, split by \t. You'll need the `forceflush` option of iperf3 to prevent buffering of the output, which would cause the awk script to print the same timestamp for each line.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Its doing the job great. :)

Comment: Just one remark: you need to add `--forceflush` to your iperf3 call to prevent it from buffering the output. Leaving this out would cause the awk script to print wrong timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the code in an arbitrary function `n() { one-liner_code_here ; }`, and run `type n`.  `bash` will flesh a lot of it out -- particularly useful is how it'll indent loops.  But `type` won't break up the pipes, and leaves semicolons behind, so here's some code to automate the whole business...

Suppose the one-liner is a file *src*.  The following puts *src* into `$x`, then makes a function *n* for it, (this requires an `eval` which for a quoted string in a function should be harmless), and `type`s it, feeds that to `sed` which ignores the surrounding brackets, breaks up the longer pipes and removes the leading indents & trailing `;`s, then `unset`s *n*:

```
read x <src; eval n\(\) \{ "$x" \;\}
type n | sed -n '/^ /{s/^    //;/^[^ ]/s/| /|\n/g;s/\;$//;p}' ; unset -f n
```

Output:

```
nice --20 iperf3 -c somelocation.com -f k |
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$(date) $line"
done |
tee onespeed.txt |
tee -a speeds.txt
sleep 30
cat onespeed.txt |
grep sender >> concentrated.txt
sleep 2
cat onespeed.txt |
grep sender |
awk -F' ' '{print $13}' |
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$(date) $line"
done |
tee onerawspeed.txt |
tee -a rawspeeds.txt
```

---

Note: `type` will also convert any `alias` in the current environment to code.  So if `grep` is `alias`ed to `grep --color=auto`, each `grep` above would be replaced with `grep --color=auto`.